# Laravel Audit and UUIDS?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, eloquent, laravel-auditing

I am using laravel auditing it shows an error on UUIDs I think, I have installed and configure the laravel auditing from http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/9.0/installation and change the user_id and id to UUIDs where the default types are bigInteger

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('audits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('user_type')->nullable();
        $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('event');
        $table->morphs('auditable');
        $table->text('old_values')->nullable();
        $table->text('new_values')->nullable();
        $table->text('url')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_agent', 1023)->nullable();
        $table->string('tags')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        
    });
}
```

I have also use the UUIDs Trait in audit.php as i am doing in my other projects model I migrated the project it created a table when i store the data it show the following error

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input
> syntax for type bigint: "974afba9-556e-4ecd-bd42-aaf12ce9aab0" (SQL:
> insert into "audits" ("old_values", "new_values", "event",
> "auditable_id", "auditable_type", "user_id", "user_type", "url",
> "ip_address", "user_agent", "tags", "id", "updated_at", "created_at")
> values ([], {"title":"Magnam nulla perfere","code":"Temporibus in ut
> cul","created_by":"2d03731c-9c71-4238-bdfc-03e3f556ddef","end_date":"2012-09-29","start_date":"2016-12-02","currency":"PKR","status":"Ongoing","budget":"32","objectives":"Architecto
> adipisci","specificobjectives":"Eveniet harum
> repre","abreviation":"Aut iusto quod
> quia","pcr_deadline":"1976-04-28","donor":"UNICEF","donor_fp_name":"Tanner
> Noble","donor_fp_email":"gyvimyz@mailinator.com","donor_fp_designation":"Ut
> vel quidem sed fa","donor_fp_mobile":"Qui sit
> provident","donor_fp_phone_office":"+1 (832)
> 163-8003","brsp_fp_email":"wygihihyw@mailinator.com","brsp_fp_name":"Myles
> Cameron","brsp_fp_designation":"Laboris ut eius ut
> e","brsp_fp_mobile":"Doloribus quis possi","brsp_fp_phone_office":"+1
> (891)
> 256-8645","reporting_frequency":"Monthly","id":"974afba9-556e-4ecd-bd42-aaf12ce9aab0","updated_at":"2021-07-13
> 15:32:09","created_at":"2021-07-13 15:32:09"}, created,
> 974afba9-556e-4ecd-bd42-aaf12ce9aab0, App\Models\Project,
> 2d03731c-9c71-4238-bdfc-03e3f556ddef, App\Models\User,
> http://localhost:8000/project/store, 127.0.0.1, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
> NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36, ?,
> eda36c0b-13c3-42c1-a345-fe2bb4b27520, 2021-07-13 15:32:09, 2021-07-13
> 15:32:09))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/9.0/audit-migration#slide-menu) states you have to do the following changes in the `audits` table migration when using UUIDs over auto-incremending IDs in your models.

> ### UUID over auto-incrementing ids
>
> Some developers prefer to use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead of auto-incrementing ids. If that's the case, make sure to update the **up()** method like so:
>
> For the `User`, change from
>
> ```php
> $table->nullableMorphs('user');
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```php
> $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable();
> $table->string('user_type')->nullable();
> $table->index([
>     'user_id', 
>     'user_type',
> ]);
> ```
>
> For the `Auditable` model, change from
>
> ```php
> $table->morphs('auditable');
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```php
> $table->uuid('auditable_id');
> $table->string('auditable_type');
> $table->index([
>    'auditable_id', 
>    'auditable_type',
> ]);
> ```

You already changed the `User` morphs, but you forgot about the `Auditable` morphs.

Comment: Also, you'll have to roll back and re-apply the new migrations (or make a change migration) if you already ran the default ones.